# sessionStorage is null on one IE 11 browser

Tags: javascript

We want to use sessionStorage to store a random browser's tab ID using the following code:

```
if (sessionStorage) {
  if (!sessionStorage.getItem("id")) {
     sessionStorage.setItem("id", getCID());
  }
  cId = sessionStorage.getItem("id")
}
```

This works for all machines and browsers like IE, Chrome, Safari, etc. But on one specific machine running Windows 10 + IE11, the sessionStorage is alway null. I have searched for similar problems, but no results. Clearing the browser's cache and cookies also did not work.

Comment: Is `window.sessionStorage` undefined or does the `id` key not have a value?

Comment: The window.sessionStorage is undefined.

Comment: Is it [disabled](http://www.techentice.com/enable-disable-dom-storage-cookies-internet-explorerfirefox/)?

Answer (score 0):

I have reset IE to factory defaults and removed all extensions. This seemed to do the trick. I suspect it was the DOM Storage that was disabled for some particular reason.